# How to implement this table view in android

Tags: android, tablerow

How to implement below image in Android.

In this view the **time row should static**, but **table row are dynamic** and each row the **cell width** is depend on time. 
Here green box are cells.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBtsJ.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the blue and green boxes dynamically and the rest is static. So you want to change the column span programmatically. To do this, first find the View you want to change using `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_sensible_id);` and then call

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
params.span = columnsToSpan;
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Where columnsToSpan is how many columns the View should occupy.

Comment: Thanks You so much sir.